R tidymodels recipes step - from a column with multiple values, create a new column for each of these values (one hot encoding)
Say i have this dataframe:
library(tidyverse)
# Sample data frame
df <- data.frame(
  id = 1:3,
  fruits = c("apple | oranges", "apple | bananas", "bananas | oranges")
)
df




id
fruits




1
apple | oranges


2
apple | bananas


3
bananas | oranges



I want to separate the values from the fruits column and then perform one hot encoding for each one as follows:
# Step 1: Separate the values based on |
df_separated <- df %>%
  separate_rows(fruits, sep = " \\| ")

# Step 2: Create a dummy variable for each element
df_dummy <- df_separated %>%
  mutate(value = TRUE) %>%
  spread(fruits, value, fill = FALSE)

# View the result
print(df_dummy)




id
apple
bananas
oranges




1
TRUE
FALSE
TRUE


2
TRUE
TRUE
FALSE


3
FALSE
TRUE
TRUE



However, I cannot manage to convert this code as a recipe step to incorporate it into a tidymodels workflow. Any ideas how to do so?

library(tidymodels)

dummies_fruit <- recipe(~ fruits, data = df) |>
  step_dummy_extract(fruits, sep = " | ") |>
  prep()

